# Unstacking repeated column in Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Given the example dataframe:

```
   Field Value
0    a     A
1    b     1
2    c     3
3    d     2 
4    e     3
5    f     1
...
```

Where the Field column repeats in groups of 6 rows (a->f). How can I unstack the dataframe using pandas?

i.e.

```
  a b c d e f
0 A 1 3 2 3 1
1 ...
.
.
.
```

I could naively do this by iteration and appending to a new dataframe. Any helpful functions to do this in pandas?

```
example_df = pd.DataFrame({'Field':['a','b','c','d','e','f'], 'Value':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
```

Comment: What determines where a new row is created? Just every 6 items?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you just need a `pivot_table`

```
>>> df.pivot_table(columns='Field', values='Value', aggfunc='first')

Field  a  b  c  d  e  f
Value  A  1  3  2  3  1
```

Answer (score 0):

If the field values always repeat from `a->f`, then you can simply `reshape` the `Value` column:

```
c = list('abcdef')
pd.DataFrame(df['Value'].values.reshape(-1, len(c)), columns=c)
```

Alternative more robust approach with `unstack`

```
i = df['Field'].eq('a').cumsum()
df.set_index([i, 'Field'])['Value'].unstack()
```

---

```
   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pivot_table` with `aggfunc=list` and then `explode` + `reset_index`:

```
tmp = df.pivot_table(columns='Field', values='Value', aggfunc=list)
tmp = tmp.explode(tmp.columns.tolist()).reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> tmp
   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
1  1  2  3  4  5  6
```

(Above output generated using your dataframe doubled.)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `idx` column to pivot on then drop it:

```
(example_df.assign(idx=example_df.Field.eq('a').cumsum())
 .pivot('idx', 'Field', 'Value').reset_index(drop = True))


Field   a   b   c   d   e   f
0       1   2   3   4   5   6
1       7   8   9  10  11  12
2      13  14  15  16  17  18
```

---

Data

```
example_df = pd.DataFrame({'Field':list('abcdef'*3), 'Value':range(1,19)})
```